# rails multiple true in form submitting string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am using rails4-autocomplete gem

In form I have

```
<%= form_for @group do |f| %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_group_name_groups_path, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true %>
 <%= f.submit "Find" %>
<% end%>
```

It is submitting params in the form of string, I want it in form of array.

Current params:

```
["NYC 1,NYC 2,"]
```

I want

```
["NYC 1","NYC 2"]
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

**`.map`** can fix your issue.

```
>> "1,2,3,4".split(",").map { |s| s }
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Same way you can do it with your code as follow:

```
"NYC 1,NYC 2,".split(",").map { |s| s }
=> ["NYC 1", "NYC 2"]
```

Comment: It will work without map with just "NYC 1,NYC 2,".split(",")
I want params to be submitted in form of array.